# Retrying a failed loop Python

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I'm running a code which runs a simulation for a given N value. I am trying to add a while loop in to retry the loop under a new N value if it fails. 
For example, if it fails for N=10, I want it to increase to N=20 and so on until it doesn't fail. At the moment I have:

```
N=0
while True:
    N=N+10
    simulation(N)
    break
```

I'm not entirely sure if I'm using 'True' correctly (I was taking it to be it runs until it doesn't fail?). I've looked at other posts asking similar things and the solutions were using exceptions, but that was when they already knew where exactly there would be a failure, whereas I don't know what values of N will fail.

Comment: How do you know whether you want to be finished or try a new `N` value? That's the part that's missing from your code.

Comment: `while boolean` will run until `boolean` is `False` or `break` happens. `True` will never be `False`.

Comment: your `while True:` statement basically mean:"Run forever". What you need is either a return value of your simulation that indicates success or failure or your simulation to throw an exception if it fails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on what you mean "fails". A possibility would be

```
N=0
while True:
    N = N+10
    try:
       simulation(N)
    except SomeError:
       pass
    else:
       break
```

That means

1. call the simulations
2. if it goes wrong (`except`) go to the next iteration (with `pass`)
3. if it succeeds (`else`) stop the loop

Take note that `else` in python can be used with `try` and `for`, but has totally different meaning than the `if-else` which appears in every language.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. My simulation will either output a summary file or not output a summary file, depending on my N. After that it tries to open the file in python, so when I say 'fail' it'll be because the file doesn't exist when I try to open it.  I'm trying your solution now to see if it works.

Comment: @NH8: ok then. run simulation and then `try open(..) except FileNotFound...`

Answer (score 0):

If you know the return value of `simulation` function, you can use it as a check if it passes or fails

```
N=0
while result:
    N=N+10
    result = simulation(N)
```

Assuming that `simulation` will return `False` when it passes else return `True`. You can negate the check if it is other way round. You should have another boundary check on `N` to exit the while loop, in case `simulation` does not pass for any values of `N`.

I also recommend to catch any exceptions to avoid ungraceful exit similar to above answer.